# class constructor not processing when called from inside another class constructor

Tags: php

I have a ready made class X

```
class X
{
   private $pA;
   function __construct($id=0)
   {
      $pA=new myClass($id);
   }
}

class myClass
{
   private $id;
   function __construct($id=0)
   {
      echo 'constructing....';
   }
}
```

But there is no echo output the class construction stops at the new operator.

sorry there is () after myclass I mistook

Comment: And why do you believe that your guess is correct?

Comment: Did you add `<?php` and `?>` on your files ? Your code works like a charme :-)

Comment: I did, I don't know why it doesn't work. I am using php53

Answer (score 2):

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `'{'' in test.php on line 11
```

change

```
class myClass()
```

to

```
class myClass
```

and actually do `new X();` and it will work as expected.

you might also want to set `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = 1` in your php.ini when developing or debugging code to see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried creating an object of type `X`?

Also, you address class members using `$this`

```
$this->pA = new myClass($id);
```

And the error that @Basti pointed out should be addressed as well.

GL~

Comment: Did you try creating an `X` object? `$myX = new X();`

Comment: @Wexas I copy+pasted the code you have above, and added `$myX = new X();` after it (all within `<?php` ... `?>` tags of course) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I took out the `()` after `myClass()` like this:

```
class myClass
{
    private $id;
    function __construct($id=0)
    {
        echo 'constructing....';
    }
}
```

Comment: And like @Shredder said, it's a good idea to use $this-> when referring to a class member variable.